# Citable reference for Auslander-Reiten formula over hereditary algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, modules, representation-theory, homological-algebra

Let $H$ be a hereditary (connected?) finite-dimensional $k$-algebra. Then for any finite-dimensional modules $X, Y$ over $H$ one has functorial isomorphisms

\begin{equation*}
\text{Ext}^{1}_H(X, Y) \cong D \text{Hom}_{H}(Y, \tau (X)) \cong D \text{Hom}_H (\tau^{-}(Y), X),
\end{equation*}

where $\tau$ and $\tau^{-}$ are the Auslander-Reiten translations.

**Question:** Do you know a citable reference for this version of the Auslander-Reiten formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are willing to cite a textbook, then the one of Assem, Simson and Skowroński, *Elements of the representation theory of associative algebras. Vol. 1*, has the following result in Chapter IV:

> **2.14. Corollary.** Let $A$ be a $K$-algebra and $M$, $N$ be two modules in $\operatorname{mod}A$.
>
> (a) If $\operatorname{pd} M \leq 1$ and $N$ is arbitrary, then there exists a $K$-linear isomorphism $$ \operatorname{Ext}^1_A(M,N) \cong D\operatorname{Hom}_A(N, \tau M). $$
>
> (b) If $\operatorname{id} N \leq 1$ and $M$ is arbitrary, then there exists a $K$-linear isomorphism $$ \operatorname{Ext}^1_A(M,N) \cong D\operatorname{Hom}_A(\tau^{-1}N, M). $$

Since the conditions $\operatorname{pd} M \leq 1$ and $\operatorname{id} N \leq 1$ are always satisfied over a hereditary algebra, this implies the result you are looking for.